# React Javascript promises with multiple functions chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have 3 functions:

One in my API file:

```
updateAPIFunction: (id, label) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        resolve();
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

One in a container React component:

```
updateParentFunction(id, label) {
    controller.updateAPIFunction(id, label).then(a => {
      return a;
    });
  }
```

and finally one in a stateless component, that is passed from the parent container:

```
this.props.updateParentFunction(id, label).then(result => {
      console.log('done')
    })
```

I am calling the function from my stateless controller, the functions is executed (the api call is made without a problem), but my stateless component returns:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I´m not completely sure on how to do this.
Should my 2nd function return a promise too?

I need to have it this way, because the stateless component will be reused by multiple parent components, which have different APIs.

Comment: You're not returning a promise from `updateParentFunction`.

Comment: change for this: updateParentFunction(id, label) {
     return controller.updateAPIFunction(id, label).then(a => {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `return` keyword in the `updateParentFunction`:

```
updateParentFunction(id, label) {
  return controller.updateAPIFunction(id, label).then(a => {
    return a;
  });
}
```

Comment: Can´t believe I missed that. Thanks!